# how to add C# codes in google colab Python code?

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I'm writing some code on google colab in python. I already have some C# code that I want resue it.

I know with below code, I can import that application to my code but I want see the codes line and change it if it was necessary.

```
import os 
os.system("myapp.exe")
```

Comment: I've never used Google Colab but I highly doubt Google will allow you to upload an executable to call from python.

Comment: Also, `os.system("myapp.exe")` does NOT import C# code into your python code, it just executes the executable and that's it. It doesn't even capture the output.

Comment: Yes, I noticed right now. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Enable SSH access in Google Colab
The first step in connecting VSCode with Google Colab is to enable SSH access in Google Colab. To do this, open a new Colab notebook and execute the following commands:

!pip install colab_ssh --upgrade
from colab_ssh import launch_ssh
launch_ssh()
These commands will install the colab_ssh library and launch an SSH server in your Colab runtime. Once the SSH server is running, you will see a message with your Colab VM’s IP address and a password. Note down these details as we will need them in the next step.

Step 2: Connect to Colab from VSCode
The next step is to connect to your Colab runtime from VSCode. To do this, we will use the Remote - SSH extension in VSCode. If you haven’t already installed this extension, you can do so by following these steps:

Open VSCode and click on the Extensions icon on the left-hand side panel.
Search for “Remote - SSH” and click on Install.
Once the extension is installed, click on the “Reload” button to activate it.
Now that we have the Remote - SSH extension installed, let’s connect to our Colab runtime:

Click on the Remote Explorer icon on the left-hand side panel.
Click on the “SSH Targets” button on the top of the panel.
Click on the “+” button to add a new SSH target.
Enter a name for the SSH target (e.g., “Colab”).
Enter the IP address and password that you noted down in Step 1.
Click on “Add SSH Host” to add the new SSH target.
Once you have added the Colab runtime as an SSH target, you can connect to it by clicking on the “Connect” button next to the target name.

Step 3: Run Code in VSCode using Colab Runtime
Now that we have connected VSCode to our Colab runtime, we can use it to run our code. To do this, we will use the VSCode Python extension, which provides an interactive Python environment and debugging tools.

Open a Python file in VSCode.
Click on the “Python: Select Interpreter” button on the bottom left-hand side of the VSCode window.
Select the Python interpreter that you want to use (e.g., Python 3.7.10 64-bit (‘Colab’)).
Once you have selected the interpreter, you can run your code by clicking on the “Run” button on the top right-hand side of the VSCode window.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).